# Emacs for Windows: How to M-x compile using MinGW_32

Tags: compilation

I have been using Console2 on an MS Windows box to compile and would like to use Emacs instead.  My settings on Console2 are as follows:

```
shell="c:/mingw/bin/sh.exe --login -i -c 'cd /c/docume~1/admini~1/desktop/;export PATH=/c/mingw/bin:/c/progra~1/git/bin; exec /bin/sh'"

init_dir=""
```

**Q**:  How can I configure Emacs to use the MinGW stuff from above so that I can run a command such as `(compile "make")` in Emacs on a Windows platform?

---

The following snippet renders an error when trying to compile Emacs from source:  "**cmdproxy.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.**"

```lisp
(defun xp-compile ()
(interactive)
(let ((default-directory (w32-short-file-name
                          "c:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/emacs"))
      (compilation-environment "PATH=/c/mingw/bin:/c/progra~1/git/bin"))
  (compile "make")))
```

[image: Example]

Comment: You ensure ‘exec-path’ contains paths to all executables needed; that ‘process-environment’ contains all environment variables needed (via e.g. ‘setenv’); then set ‘compile-command’ as ‘cd <path> && make’ and call M-x compile. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: @InHarmsWay -- Thank you for reading and responding to this particular thread.  I am familiar with setting the `process-environment` variable and generally like to do so on a let-bound basis when calling a custom version of `start-process` (which calls `make-process` ...).  In the context of this particular question, I am unsure whether I need `sh.exe --login -i -c` to be able to compile using Emacs on a Windows platform and/or whether I also need `exec /bin/sh` somewhere in the setup; and, if I need those, then where/how to configure that ...?

Comment: @InHarmsWay -- I have updated the question with a screenshot and sample function which generates the following error when trying to compile Emacs from source:  "**cmdproxy.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.**"

Comment: PATH on windows uses ; as separator, for one thing. Other than that, have you tried simple commands as dummy compile-command’s, like pwd or echo %PATH%, as a means of sanity-checking the shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example sets the `shell-file-name` to the absolute path of the `sh.exe` executable.  Without that setting, `cmdproxy.exe` will complain as depicted in the screenshot in the question above.

The `default-directory` is hard-coded for the sake of creating a minimal working example.

Inasmuch as MinGW uses Unix flavor PATH separators, this example uses colons instead of semicolons.

The `process-environment` (containing a custom PATH for MinGW and Git executables) is set on a temporary basis for the duration of the function, which is simply a personal preference.

The following approach is based upon the helpful comments of @npostavs below, which suggested a simplification of the alternative answer such that the existing value of PATH will be shadowed by a user-specified path.

```lisp
(defun mingw-compile (command)
(interactive)
(let* ((shell-file-name "c:/mingw/bin/sh.exe")
       (default-directory (w32-short-file-name
         "c:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/emacs/"))
       (mingw+git "/c/mingw/bin:/c/progra~1/git/bin")
       (process-environment (cons (concat "PATH=" mingw+git) process-environment)))
  (compile command)))
```

Alternative approach that does *not* shadow the existing PATH and instead replaces it entirely on a temporary basis:

```lisp
(defun mingw-compile (command)
(interactive)
(let* ((shell-file-name "c:/mingw/bin/sh.exe")
       (default-directory (w32-short-file-name
         "c:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/emacs/"))
       (mingw+git "/c/mingw/bin:/c/progra~1/git/bin")
       ;; (path (concat (getenv "PATH") ":" mingw+git))
       (temp (mapcar 'concat process-environment))
       (newenv (setenv-internal temp "PATH" mingw+git t))
       (process-environment newenv))
  (compile command)))
```

Comment: You can bind `process-environment` to `(cons (concat "PATH=" mingw+git) process-environment)` instead of the last 3 let-bindings.

Comment: @npostavs -- When you have time, could please help me understand what happens if we use `(cons (concat "PATH=" mingw+git) process-environment)`?  On a Windows box, I saw stuff in the default PATH that MinGW would not be interested in using; e.g., `"C:\\Program Files\\Parallels\\Parallels Tools\\Applications;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\WestLCFs"`.  I wanted to eliminate those inapplicable paths from the MinGW build process.  Does your suggested edit place the desired paths in front of the list such that the latter is effectively *shadowed*?

Comment: Only the first `"PATH=..."` entry in `process-environment` gets used, so yes, my suggestion will shadow any existing value of `PATH`.

Comment: @npostavs -- Thank you for the explanation of the suggested edit.  I have edited the answer above to include your suggestion as the primary answer.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant by "shadowed". In fact, both alternatives have the same effect: to replace the value of `PATH` over the scope of the `let` body. My suggestion was just to shorten your code a bit.

Comment: @npostavs -- In your example, the `process-environment` contains two (2) values for PATH; i.e., `(PATH=/c/mingw/bin:/c/progra~1/git/bin PATH=C:\Program Files\Parallels\Parallels Tools\Applications;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\WestLCFs)`.  In my example, the `process-environment` contains just one (1) value for the PATH; i.e., `(PATH=/c/mingw/bin:/c/progra~1/git/bin)`.  What I meant by the term "shadowed" is that in your example, the second definition for PATH is ignored.  I opted to comment out `(path (concat (getenv "PATH") ":" mingw+git))` ...