# Configure compilation mode to use custom shell

Tags: projectile, compilation-mode

On windows I have set `(setq explicit-shell-file-name "c:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe")` to use git-bash for e.g. `M-x shell`. In compilation mode however, the standard windows console still seems to be used, as far as I can tell. Can this be changed somehow?

FWIW, I'm actually using projectile-run-project to trigger compilation in this particular scenario.
One possible solution is to place `(projectile-project-run-cmd . "\"c:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe\" build_and_run.sh")` in `.dir-locals.el`, but then I cannot use the same dir-locals on linux. It is important that the output of `build_and_run.sh` is displayed in compilation-mode, because it might contain links with build errors.

Comment: `explicit-shell-file-name` is *only* for `M-x shell`. Does it work to set `shell-file-name` instead?

Comment: Seems to work fine!

Comment: The problem is, that this will cause other issues. For example I get messages like this now, when counsel-etags calls grep: `A path separator must be exactly one byte, but the given separator is 21 bytes: C:/Program Files/Git/
In some shells on Windows '/' is automatically expanded. Use '//' instead.`

Comment: Here is a link to an example of how I use Emacs (for Windows) to build Emacs (for Windows) with the MinGW library:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48316/2287  In the linked example, I use the MinGW `sh.exe` as the custom shell in `compilation-mode`.  I have never used projectile.