# How do I make compilation use vterm instead of the default shell it is using?

Tags: shell, compile

I am running `M-x compile` commands in my Projectile projects. I would like to use vterm for running them as the compilations are getting very slow because the project is very large.

How do I make compilation use `vterm` instead of the default shell it is using?

Comment: I don't know what `vterm` is, but I was able to use `compile` on another platform than my daily machine by setting the `shell-file-name`.  Perhaps your issue is similar -- see my solution in a potentially related thread:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48316/2287

Comment: @lawlist vterm is an alternative Emacs shell to shell, eshell, term, etc which uses a module linked to libvterm.